# Calculating a relaxed Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangulations

The triangles of a planar Delaunay Triangulations are essentially characterized by the property that no triangle's corner is inside another triangle's circumcircle; Delaunay Triangulations can be calculated in $O\left(n\log n\right)$ time.

> **Questions:**
>
> - Does relaxing the definition of Delaunay Triangulations by replacing the term "circumcircle" with "enclosing ellipse of least area" (i.e. the [Steiner circumellipse](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerCircumellipse.html)) but keeping the "empty interior" requirement suffice to uniquely define a triangulation or do we have to add a requirement such as that the sum of ellipse-areas be minimal?
> - Can the "relaxed" Delaunay Triangulation also be calculated in subquadratic time, maybe from the "ordinary" Delaunay Triangulation?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that enclosing ellipses of the least area define a triangulation in a reasonable way. Consider the following six points (first on the circle and then possibly wiggle them a little bit if you do not want them on the circle): $a = (1, 0)$, $b = (0,1)$, $c$ and $d$ are close to $(-1,0)$ and $e$ and $f$ are close to $(0,-1)$. The least area ellipse passing through $a, c, d$ does not contain other points (neither on the boundary nor in the interior). Similarly, the least area ellipse passing through $b, e, f$ does not contain other points. However the triangles $acd$ and $bef$ intersect, thus they cannot be both in the triangulation. This says that at least the naive approach: Taking those triangles which have the least area ellipse not containg other points cannot work.

I doubt whether some other extra conditions will save this example. But of course it depends what exactly is the requirement. If the requirement is that you take a triangulation for which the sum of the areas of the least area ellipses is minimal, then this is a triangulation. (But I see no guarantee that, in general, the least area ellipses do not contain other points for this triangulation.)

Comment: I agree with the genral concern that such a triangulation need not exist in general but I also suspect that these situations are rare for instances that haven't been specifically designed to demonstrate nonexistence.

Comment: Really? The point of Delaunay triangulations is to avoid "spiky" triangles. On the other hand, for ellipses, if I have a spiky triangle, then the least area ellipse is small and thus it may likely avoid other points. In my opinion something like this will be a typical case.

Comment: One more remark for the more general question specifically for the sum of the areas of the ellipses: I have just noticed that the ratio of the area of the Steiner circumellipse and the base triangle is constant, namely $\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$. (This pointed out in the link provided in the question). Thus the sum of the areas of the ellipses is independent of the triangulation, namely $\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$ times the area of the convex hull of the points.

Comment: so we must resort to sum of squared areas.